# Calling a Lua function passing as function argument from C++

Tags: c++, c, lua

Can you please tell me how to call a function from the Lua Table with parameters passed to it in the form of functions?

That is, here is an analogue of the code in Lua:

```
local my_table_= func_Lua(param_1, param_2)
 
//That is, the func_Lua function returned a table that contains, for example, the Set_Callback function.
 
 
 
//Calling Set_Callback in turn requires parameters - this is the table itself and the callback function:
 
my_table_:Set_Callback(function(idx)my_callback_(param_1, param_2) end)
```

The callback function itself:

```
function my_callback_(param_1, param_2)
 
...code
 
end
```

In Lua it is clear how to do this, but here's how to do the analog, but in C ++?

C++:

```
//In L - at the top of the stack there is already a table returned by func_Lua.
 
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Set_Callback"); // "I pop" the Set_Callback function to the top of the stack from the "table".
```

Now I need to put the parameters of the Set_Callback function on the stack in sequence, but I can’t figure it out anymore:

-how to put function(idx)

-how to put my_callback_

Can't figure out where my callback function should be declared? In a Lua script, and then I just need to get it through Lua_global or in C ++?

Answer (score 0):

If the Lua's virtual stack (from within `C++`) looks like this:

```
2: param_2
1: param_1
0: mycallback
```

you'd call it like this:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "mycallback");  /* function to be called */
lua_pushnumber(L, param_1);   /* 1st argument - assuming number*/
lua_pushnumber(L, param_2);   /* 2nd argument - assuming number */

/* do the call (2 arguments, 1 result) */
if (lua_pcall(L, 2, 1, 0) != 0)
  fprintf(stderror, "error running function `mycallback': %s",
                 lua_tostring(L, -1));
```

Comment: This does a protected call (`pcall`). The equivalent of the shown Lua code would be an unprotected call.